# Laravel kick user via session

Tags: php, session, laravel

I want to be able to kick logged in users via their sessions...

So what I want to do is to delete a session in my database (structure below)
And so "kick" the user from te logged in users.

How Can I get the session of all the users and merge them to the users?

So like session ID `d98af07db237867a62e8ee53b372847f89363eae` Belongs to User `Robin`.

But session ID `dsdfjsmoijqsfqsfsqf5qs54fq5f4s6f4s6d54f` Belongs to user `Patrick`.

My database looks like the standard of Laravel so id, payload and last_activity.

Hope someone can help me out.

Comment: Do you use the `database` driver for sessions?

Comment: You could possibly alter laravel's session table by adding a new field for the id of the user, and then update the same session table when the user logs in.

Comment: Yes I do. use the Database driver @MarcoPallante

Comment: Why on earth do you want to log a user out like this? Have you considered the fact that it's very likely there's a proper way to accomplish what you're trying to do? If you explain what you are trying to achieve then someone may suggest a far better solution.

Comment: I just want to be able to kick the users via their sessions.

Comment: I don't think it's easy to accomplish. As @Avalanche said, you may add a field for the user id, but how would you use it? You should make a new custom version of the session driver, to fill that info... I think it's a little cumbersome.

Comment: As @Brett said, maybe it's better to rethink what you want to get and how to do that.

Comment: Another idea is to play with the session lifetime (see ```app/config/session.php```), and probably lower that value down to fit your needs.

Comment: No no and no... I appreciate yout help like this, but I want to be alble to destroy a session of a logged in user to take away his logged in rights. I added now a column with a fillable id. So if the user logs in, the id filles in with the users ID. Later I'll join the user and session table.

Comment: I totally understand you, @Robin, and I don't understand why there is need to justify the action. 
Anyway, here it goes a case (reason why I landed here). I found a user that for some reason a Laravel Nova page keeps reloeading over and over, every minute. I need to kill the session and force it to go to home page on the next request.